# Отслеживание интернет-трафика C#

Tags: c#, сеть, трафик

День добрый, друзья! Возможно ли средствами C# вести учёт размера входящих/исходящих пакетов? Сколько я отправил байтов, сколько получил и т.п., используя Wi-Fi. Есть ли у кого примеры?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант для подсчёта всего трафика:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     PerformanceCounterCategory performanceCounterCategory = new PerformanceCounterCategory("Network Interface");
     string instance = performanceCounterCategory.GetInstanceNames()[0]; // 1st NIC !
     PerformanceCounter performanceCounterSent = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Sent/sec", instance);
     PerformanceCounter performanceCounterReceived = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Received/sec", instance);

     for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("bytes sent: {0}k\tbytes received: {1}k", performanceCounterSent.NextValue() / 1024, performanceCounterReceived.NextValue() / 1024);
          Thread.Sleep(500);
     }
 }
```

Рекомендую выводить именно в **килобайтах**,а **не в байтах**. Если вы всё же хотите в байтах, то уберите в `Console.WriteLine` - `/1024`

Подключить директивы:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Трафик при запуски видео в 720p, к примеру:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если говорить о методе `PerformanceCounterCategory.GetInstanceNames ()` в целом, то он извлекает список экземпляров объекта производительности, связанный с категорией `Network Interface`. А если брать в отдельности `GetInstanceNames ()`, то он содержит массив строк, представляющих имена экземпляров объекта производительности, связанных с этой категорией. Проще говоря `GetInstanceNames ()` возвращает имя сети. Подробнее на [официальном сайте](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagn..(v=vs.110).aspx)

`[0]` у `GetInstanceNames()` - номер массива `Network Interface`. `[0]` является `Network Interface'ом` по умолчанию. Можно использовать и другие массивы `GetInstanceNames()`. Проще всего узнать доступные имена `Network Interface` через отладчик.

К примеру у меня два `performanceCounterCategory.GetInstanceNames()[]`:

1) Первое (нулевой массив) именуется как **802.11n USB Wireless LAN Card**

2) Второе (первый массив) называется как **Intel[R] Ethernet Connection I217-V**