# Получить название сетевых подключений c#

Tags: c#, сеть

Доброго времени суток, не подскажите, как получить имена (или пути) всех сетевых соединений ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например : `nobilis,server,workstation1` и тп (скрин выше). Получить диски `c,d,q` можно таким образом :

```
var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
```

А как получить сетевые соединения ? И можно ли будет обращаться к файлам таким же способом, как и для обычных файлов ? спасибо за ответ

Comment: Могу ошибаться, так как не очень понял вопрос. Вам имена не сетевых ли интерфейсов нужны - `performanceCounterCategory.GetInstanceNames()[]`? Подробнее [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669494/248502).

Comment: @Egor возможно, я не силен в определениях и точных названиях, к сожалению. Скрин выше, мне нужно получить имя или путь ко всем доступным соединениям (`nobilis(\\NOBILIS),server(\\SERVER),xray(\\XRAY)`) и тп

Comment: @Egor нашел такой пример [ссылка](https://pastebin.com/BHRdF7Z2 ) но он выводит только 1 имя пк (NOBILIS), а остальные нет

Comment: Замените в `static void Main()` - `ArrayList list = GetServerList(SV_101_TYPES.SV_TYPE_WORKSTATION);` на `ArrayList list = GetServerList(SV_101_TYPES.SV_TYPE_ALL);`

Comment: спасибо, попробуй, а с этими сетевыми соединениями можно так же работать, как и с обычным диском ? Например, чтоб получить все файлы на диске С я пишу `Directory.GetFiles("C:\\", "*.*"); ` а для данного случая  выполнится ли `Directory.GetFiles("\\\\SERVER", "*.*");` ?

Comment: @Egor я могу получить список файлов и папок только зная заранее имя папки, которая там есть. Например : подключена машина `\\SERVER` в ней находится 2 папки(`temp1, temp2` ) и 1 файл (`file1`), содержимое корня `\\SERVER` я не могу узнать, но вот содержимое папок могу `\\SERVER\temp1` или `\\SERVER\temp2`

Comment: @Egor можно ли как-то получить содержимое корня \\SERVER ? а именно сами директории `temp1, temp2`

Comment: выдает ошибку "The UNC path should be of the form \\server\share"